# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance' in django at the time of form editing with image field in django

Tags: python, django

forms.py

```
class edit_product_data_check(forms.Form):

    class Meta:
        model = product_data
        fields = '_all_'
```

views.py

```
def update_product_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    # Get the posted form
        p_id=request.POST.get("product_id", "")

      product_edit = get_object_or_404(product_data, id=p_id)
      form = edit_product_data_check(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product_edit)
      if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('product'))`
```

Comment: Note also, `_all_` should be `__all__`.

Answer (score 5):

You're subclassing a vanilla [`Form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/forms/#Form) when you should be subclassing [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform):

```
class EditProductDataCheckForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
```